# The user profile page is not displayed right in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page

Admittedly, this is not a *colossal* problem, but it's been bugging me a bit nevertheless.

In Chrome, user profile pages look like the screenshot below. As you can see, the "About me"-section is below the rest of the information, making the whole page look a bit strange.

This is the only network site I've seen this on, it's even correct on the meta-page. It looks OK in both IE and FF. I'm using Chrome 39.0.2171.95.

I have this both on my work computer and at home. I'm using Win 7 and Win 8, both 64-bit versions, if that's of any relevance. I don't have an adblocker installed, so that's not what's causing it.

Is it possible to fix this?

[image]

It looks fine in Chrome when I use an IE "simulator":

[image]

Comment: Are you using CSS overlays (or whatever that's called?) Maybe this is a question for UX.SE?

Comment: Looks OK to me in Chrome & FF, but someone else had the same recently: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4038/about-me-box-on-user-page-not-in-the-right-place

Comment: @PeterJ, I haven't seen that post until now. I'm surprised me and tcrosley have the same problem, but in different browsers.

Comment: Do you happen to be zoomed out (I can reproduce when at 90% zoom)? Try hitting `Ctrl + 0` to reset zoom level to the default.

Comment: @Oded: Yes, and wow... That was super strange, because EE.SE (both on main and meta side) are the only websites where I have default zoom 90%. I checked SO before changing the zoom, and it was 100% there. The strangest thing is that I have those settings on two computers. Wouldn't surprise me if google registered my setting and duplicated it to my computer at work. Now it's an even smaller problem than before, but I imagine it should be an easy fix, seeing that all other sites on the network shows it right. Thanks!

Comment: Accepted! I think I'll be able to live with the fact that it doesn't look 100% right, when I'm only asking for 90% =P I was more wondering if this was a bug, in which case I thought it was worth bringing up. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if you are zoomed out - I was able to reproduce with zoom of 90%.

However, we don't support zooming - visual artifacts like this can be expected, but will not be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Chrome (version 39.0217199 m) on Win 7 64-bit, and I don't see this problem:

[image]

Comment: By the way: That's my meta-profile page, and it looks OK for me too. It's the main user page that's incorrect. Does that one look correct for you too?

Comment: Updated with what I'm seeing on your main EE.SE profile.

Answer (score 0):

Also to me looks fine: Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m

[image]